# ASP.NET Core hosted on Ubuntu as a PWA gets error "insecure manifest" and blocks service worker

Tags: asp.net-core, https, manifest.json

I'm hosting a .NET Core Progressive Web App (PWA) on Ubuntu using a Squid reverse-proxy. When I launch in developer mode (HTTP), my PWA works normally.

However, when I run it through the proxy in production for HTTPS, I get an error in Chrome dev tools telling my that my manifest file is insecure (i.e. it's being giving `http://...manifest.json` instead of `https`). The service worker is blocked and I basically have just a website. Any clues as to how to tell .NET Core to send the manifest file with an `https` link?

I have tried combinations of adding `app.UseHsts();` and `app.UseHttpsRedirection();` to the startup.cs file and I even added `.UseSetting("https_port", "443")` to Program.cs which makes Squid block all but the top page.

The Console tab error in Chrome Dev tools is:

> Mixed Content: The page at 'https://xxxx.com/home/privacy' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure manifest 'http://xxxx/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fmanifest.webmanifest'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: Can you specify the web-server you are serving this application from? I believe you need to configure the web server for HTTPS before you'll be able to use https redirection for your application. This could also require a valid SSL certificate (from a certificate authority) if Chrome expects the certificate to be trusted as a heads up.

Comment: The public LetsEncrypt cert for this domain is already on the proxy server (and renews automatically every 60 days) which is setup to serve multiple sites on different servers. That proxy system is running Squid reverse proxy. The dot net core system is running Ubuntu with a standard Ubuntu LAMP install. Squid is receiving port 443 traffic and forwarding it to port 80 o f the dot net core system.

Comment: Works great except that the .net core app server does not know to tell clients to get the https version of the files. I'm not sure if I can just completely flip the app server to HTTPS without any header changes on Squid. Can I just tell the .net server to send every link to clients as https and not worry about actually running/serving https files (since Squid will take care of that). Any thoughts... and by the way please don't ask me to simplify the environment, it is what I am giving and i'm not the only site on the setup.

Comment: One thing I could think of trying would be to use your HTTPS certificate on both servers, the purpose there being that if you run the .NET core app server in HTTPS, you might not need to fight it to serve everything over HTTPS instead of HTTP.